# Probability of a word where 2 letters do not follow each other

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

I have seven letters, say A, B, C, D, E, E, G. I have figured out how many distinct possible combinations I can have as $7!/2!$. My question is, how many of these will have the two E's separated?

I was drawing to draw up pictures to these to map it out of what the possibilities would look like, but I got nowhere with that pretty fast. I am pretty stumped on how to think of these and I was mainly wondering if I could get some assistance in the thought process behind it and any tips on how to think about it in general. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Can you count how many of these will have the two $E's$ together?

Then subtract that number from $\dfrac{7!}{2!}$

Comment: would that be $6*5!$?

Comment: @Jack: Yes- that's right.

Comment: thanks. I feel like half the problem is seeing these in a certain light.

Comment: @Jack: In probability questions, if you can't calculate something, always see if you can compute the "complement".

Answer (score 0):

A few different ways to approach this are possible. Maybe the quickest to understand is to place the two Es first, "legally", $7\times 6/2-6=15$ ways then add the remaining letters into the remaining 5 slots.